# Transform a number saved as a string, and output it as a whole number

Tags: java

I am currently stuck on a Java Class assignment. I have a premade program that I have to modify so that it outputs the desired output.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Read double precision numbers from standard input and print only
 * their integer part to standard output, this is, truncating its decimals
 */
public class Solution
{
    /**
     * Gets data from standard input
     */
    private Scanner input = null;

    /**
     * Start the execution of the solution
     * @param args Command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Solution solution = new Solution();
        solution.run();
    }

    /**
     * Run the solution. This method is called from main()
     */
    public void run()
    {
        // Create object to read data from standard input
        this.input = new Scanner(System.in);


        // This code replicates the input to the standard output
        // Modify this code to solve the problem
        while ( this.input.hasNextLine() )
        {
            System.out.println(  this.input.nextLine() );
        }

        // Close the standard input
```

The lines that I am allowed to modify are

```
while ( this.input.hasNextLine() )
        {
            System.out.println(  this.input.nextLine() );
        }
```

The given input is:

```
0.978
-14.7
109
-1.0
00.00000000000
12908350467.480081110
```

And the desired output is

```
0
-14
109
-1
0
12908350467
```

The issue I am having is the fact that these are being entered into the program as strings (as suggested by "hasNextLine"). How should I go about this?

*Sorry in advance if I did not explain myself properly*

Comment: Take a look at the other methods of the [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html) class, particularly those that start with `next...`

Comment: You could take the "line" returned from `nextLine` and pass it through another `Scanner` to parse it.  Alternatively, you could use `Double.parseDouble` to parse the `String` directly